# Drive is still 8gb after attempt to expand by 30gb, windows 2000

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2000

Drive is still 8gb after attempt to expand by 30gb! Disk management even shows it as 38gb! This is a windows 2000 VM. See picture.[image]

Comment: Do you have a question? What tells you the drive is only 8GB? Some relevant information really wouldn't go astray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you expanded the DISK but not the partition on the disk. First, take a FULL backup of the VM files, then use a GPartEd bootable ISO and boot the guest off that and expand the partition to fill the rest of the disk. I prefer Acronis Disk Director for such things, but that's not free :)

Comment: oh wow, I just noticed that it actually reports the C volume as 38GB, I'd still boot off the ISO and see what a 3rd party tool sees.

Comment: Gparted worked like magic